# Is it possible to apply "IsValid" on a certain div only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have multiple divs in my webpage containing different forms, but only one of them is visible at a time, I was wondering if it's possible to only validate one div from code behind.

```
<div runat="server" id="Div1">
  //some form with validators
  //sumbit button
 </div>

 <div runat="server" id="Div2">
  //some form with validators
 //sumbit button
</div>
```

I need to do something like this :

```
if ((reference only the div I want).IsValid){
  //do stuff
 }
 else {
 //do other stuff
 }
```

Comment: instead of do if or if. Maybe doing in client side <div id=1><form></form><div>, <div id=2><form></form><div> and adding in each form a submit button or on toolbar submit button and in the server catch the same post, doing it so the method isInvalid works on each form in transparent mode

Comment: @CarlosCocom can you please clarify more? the code behind part. Thanks :) (PS: I couldn't fin a "isInvalid" method)

Comment: sorry @Mehdi El Morabit the method is "ModelState.IsValid" i was wrong. Your action is an endpoint so for example with jquey $("form:first").submit(); with that line you can invoke the action if each div you add a form you could invoke each div regardless which is. asp.net mvc allow do it

Comment: i forget you dont can repeat element names but you can hide it and populate before of the submit action

Comment: @CarlosCocom Thanks for yoru effort ^^ I just went with a client side verification :)